# Does prior illegal police action render possession of prescription medication involuntary?

Tags: criminal-law, us-constitution, florida

Does prior illegal police action render possession of prescription medication involuntary?

For example, police filling a fraudulent prescription through a pharmacist instead of making an arrest.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't clear that the example you give is illegal police action, but let's assume that it is for the sake of this question, since it doesn't affect the analysis.

If possession is not compelled, then it is voluntary.